# Simple gender radio buttons in Rails (including labels and i18n)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, radio-button

I'm currently working on a Rails app. In the app it should be possible to edit the gender of a user.

I wanted to implement this via a radio box (as it is often done). This is what I came up with:

```
form_for @user do |f|
  - [:female, :male].each do |gender|
    = f.label :gender, t(:"helpers.label.member.gender_#{gender}"), value: gender
    = f.radio_button :gender, gender, checked: @user.gender == gender
```

I wanted remove as much logic from the view as possible and tried to build the same with a view helper but failed badly.

How can specify a helper method, so that a simple

```
f.gender_select
```

or

```
f.gender_select @member
```

just shows the correct radio box?

Also how do I specify the label for the individual select options in a way, that the Rails i18n takes advantage of it (e.g. `f.label :first_name` will automatically be translated)

Answer (score 2):

```
form_for @user do |form|
  - gender_radio_buttons(form)
```

application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def gender_radio_buttons(form)
    [ :female, :male ].map do |gender|
      form.label(:gender, t(:"helpers.label.member.gender_#{gender}"), value: gender) +
      form.radio_button(:gender, gender, checked: @user.gender == gender)
    end.join("\n")
  end
```

Comment: Looks good, there are however some problems with this approach: not as easy to test (I don't want to go into mocking a Form object) 2. not quite as I imagined (gender_radio_buttons(form) instead of form.gender_radio_buttons)

Comment: The call gender_radio_buttons(form) is how helpers work.  For a call to be form.gender_radio_buttons, then gender_radio_buttons would have to be in the class for the form object.  I have considered a design alternative to the way Rails works, with a View class, and instead of methods in the helpers module, you would actually define methods in the view class.  (Maybe with a different way of passing data from controllers to views than using the controller objects instance variables.)

Comment: This answer was for how to do it with a helper.  You weren't getting how helpers would need to work.  An alternative approach would be to use a partial view.  You will still have to pass the form object, in locals.  It might address the testing issue, since if you don't test your views, you wouldn't mind skipping it for testing, and if you do test views, you might be able to adapt your methodology for testing views to the partial.